# What are the rules of when propel's toArray() function will return referenced objects or just the top level?

Tags: php, mysql, propel

I can't seem to nail the exact rule of thumb as to what is added to an array when using `toArray()`, insomuch that if I was to do something like this:

```
$sheep = SheepQuery::create()->find();
foreach ($sheep as $sheepii) {
  $sheepii->getShepherd();
}
return $sheep->toArray();
```

or some variation of it, sometimes I seem to get results with both the columns from the sheep table *and* their sub-arrays with the shepherd, but sometimes it doesn't seem to include it, so I have to do something like add the values to a new array as I loop over.

Can anyone point out (a link explaining) why this happens and the rules behind it so I'm not blindly guessing, and if there's a nicer way of doing the same thing above by all means I'm open to suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually, if you want a relation to be inside the `toArray()` you need to fetch it *or* make a join inside the initial query.

This will return only information for objects `Sheep`:

```
$sheep = SheepQuery::create()
  ->find();
$sheep->toArray();
```

This will return informations for objects `Sheep` **and** their relation to `Shepherd` if there is one:

```
$sheep = SheepQuery::create()
  ->find()
  ->joinWith('Shepherd');
$sheep->toArray();
```

And here is a good blog post about [Getting To Know Propel 1.5: When You Really Need Arrays](http://propelorm.org/blog/2010/05/17/getting-to-know-propel-1-5-when-you-really-need-arrays.html).

Comment: Also worth mentioning the `$includeForeignObjects` of the `toArray()` method from that link (which defaults to false) - thanks

Comment: To bad the link isn't available anymore.